# Can't use $_post value as table name for mysql in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm working on a blog right now that aims to display messages to only people it belongs to, so I have a select in html where people can select a person and then it sends it to that table in MySQL.

What I now have in the index.html:

```
<form action="post.php" method="post">
                <label>Naam:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Naam" class="form-control">
                <label>Voor wie is dit bericht bestemd?</label>
                <select name="portal" class="form-control">
                    <option id="0">Selecteer</option>
                    <option id="1">Leerlingen</option>
                    <option id="2">Docenten</option>
                    <option id="3">Ouders</option>
                    <option id="4">Bedrijven</option>
                </select>
        </div>
        <div class="paper col-sm-6">
                <label>Email:</label>
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
                <label>Onderwerp:</label>
                <input type="textarea" class="form-control" placeholder="Onderwerp" name="subject"/>
        </div>
        <div class="paper col-sm-12">
                <label>Korte informatie:</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="textarea" name="short"/>
                <label>Volledige informatie</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" cols="50" name="long"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="paper col-sm-12 text-center">
                <div class="col-xs-12" style="height:25px;"></div>
                <button class="btn btn-default">Verstuur!</button>
            </form>
```

and this in my post.php:

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "a1070rik";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "portals";
    $title = '$_POST[subject]';
    $by = '$_POST[name]';
    $short = '$_POST[short]';
    $long = '$_POST[long]';
    $portal = '$_POST[portal]';

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO $portal (id, title, by, short, long)
VALUES ('', $title, $by, $short, $long)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

When I try to run it it gives me this vague error:

```
Error: INSERT INTO $_POST[portal] (id, title, by, short, long) VALUES ('', $_POST[subject], $_POST[name], $_POST[short], $_POST[long])
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[portal] (id, title, by, short, long) VALUES ('', $_POST[subject], $_POST[name],' at line 1
```

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Thanks everyone that helped,

this code eventually worked for me:

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "a1070rik";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "portals";
    $title = $_POST['subject'];
    $by_information = $_POST['name'];
    $short = $_POST['short'];
    $long_information = $_POST['long'];
    $portal = $_POST['portal'];

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO  $portal (`id`, `title`, `info_bys`, `info_shorts`, `info_longs`) VALUES ('', '$title', '$by', '$short', '$long')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: `'$_POST[subject]';` is the literal string `'$_POST[subject]';` actually, mind that - and you must quote a string before insertion. All of this if you still want to have unsecured and vulnerable queries, of course

Comment: THIS DESIGN IS DANGEROUSLY BROKEN!  You are going to be wide open to an SQL injection attack if you continue down this path.  https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: by is the reserved word use it like this with `by` i mean ```by`` like this

Comment: Why do you have multiple database tables with the exact same structure?

Comment: Its like a blog that is for teachers, students, parents etc. So it the posts for parents can't be visible for students etc.

Comment: long is also reserved word, escapte that too https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`$_POST` works like an array So you will need to get values from `$_POST` by his `indexs` i.e in your case `subject`,`name` etc. So Remove `'` while assigning the values to variable.

```
$title = $_POST['subject'];
$by = $_POST['name'];
$short = $_POST['short'];
$long = $_POST['long'];
$portal = strtolower($_POST['portal']);
```

***NOTE : The names 'by,long' are MySQL reserved keywords. So Change them.***

Update your SQL from

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO $portal (id, title, by, short, long) VALUES ('', '$title', '$by', '$short', '$long')";
```

TO

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO  $portal (`id`, `title`, `info_bys`, `info_shorts`, `info_longs`) VALUES ('', '$title', '$by', '$short', '$long')";
```

Your sql is vulnerable So use

```
// prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO  $portal (`title`, `info_bys`, `info_shorts`, `info_longs`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param($title, $by, $short, $long);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks it worked kind of, but now i have a new error,

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'by, short, long) VALUES ('', awcacawdca, acawcac, adawdad, dadadwd)' at line 1

Comment: by which he is using in the column name is a reserved word, my english is short, but he need to escape it

Comment: @RikNijdeken : The names 'by,long' are MySQL reserved keywords

Comment: @RikNijdeken : yes. Change `by` to `by_information` and `long` to `long_information`.

Comment: just escape they by using this ` on both sides, long and by

Comment: @urfusion tried to edit it, still got the same error.

Comment: @arif_suhail_123 could you give me an example of escaping it, im pretty noob

Comment: read this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17634915/how-to-escape-reserved-mysql-words-in-query-in-php

Comment: @RikNijdeken : can you print your query.

Comment: @urfusion okay $sql = "INSERT INTO $portal (id, title, by, short, long) VALUES ('', '$title', '$by', '$short', '$long')";

Comment: Could it be because of the select says Bedrijven with a uppercase B and the mysql table has wih a lowercase b

Comment: According to the code I have updated. now it should work. and the query will be like `INSERT INTO portal (`id`, `title`, `info_bys`, `info_shorts`, `info_longs`) VALUES ('', 'sadf', 'name', 'short', 'long')`

Comment: Good luck andyway as soon as someone enters a `'` in the title field

Comment: This solution is still dangerously broken!  If someone puts a ' in the input then they can still break out of the expected SQL and execute arbitrary SQL commands.  Use the proper escaping mechanisms such as mysqli_real_escape_string or prepared statements.  Also, there's no way a user should be able to supply a table name.  That's dangerous in all kinds of ways.  Go back and rethink your design and your data validation.

Comment: @RikNijdeken It didn't work, it just gave you a result you were expecting.  There's a world of difference.  This code is still broken.

Comment: @GordonM it doesnt need to be safe at this point, its still a pilot so i will fix it in the future

Comment: @RikNijdeken "We'll do it properly later": The credo of a million broken lines of code

Comment: @GordonM : yes I know this query is vulnerable for sql injections. My first priority was to provide a solution for the user so he can set code in working condition first.

Comment: @urfusion For the reasons I've already mentioned in my comments.  At least change `$var = $_POST ['var']` to `$var = mysqli_real_escape_string ($_POST ['var'])`

Answer (score -2):

Dont use variables as strings. Keep it organized and fool proof:

```js
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "a1070rik";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "portals";
    $title = $_POST['subject'];
    $by = $_POST['name'];
    $short = $_POST['short'];
    $long = $_POST['long'];
    $portal = $_POST['portal'];

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$portal = $mysqli->real_escape_string($portal);
$title = $mysqli->real_escape_string($title);
$by = $mysqli->real_escape_string($by);
$short = $mysqli->real_escape_string($short);
$long = $mysqli->real_escape_string($long);

$sql = "INSERT INTO `".$portal."` (id, title, by, short, long) VALUES ('', '".$title."', '".$by."', '".$short."', '".$long."')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Good luck andyway as soon as someone enters a `'` in the title field

Comment: This solution is still dangerously broken! If someone puts a ' in the input then they can still break out of the expected SQL and execute arbitrary SQL commands. Use the proper escaping mechanisms such as mysqli_real_escape_string or prepared statements. Also, there's no way a user should be able to supply a table name. That's dangerous in all kinds of ways. Go back and rethink your design and your data validation

Comment: he asked how to make it work, looking at the HTML it's an environment which is controlled, to make it safe he should use a escape string but i doubt that he will know what it is and that will make it harder

Comment: That's no excuse.  Either do it properly or not at all, giving people "solutions" that can lead to dangerous practices is not helping anybody.